# How to edit source code of a class like `ScaleGestureDetector` or whatever?

Tags: android

I have tried to change the way how `ScaleGestureDetector` uses motion events, because of it uses methods like `getX()` and `getY()`, but instead I want it to use `getRawX()` and `getRawY()`. I just wanna change that and do it by that way. So, how can I change the code of a class like this or `ImageView`, etc...?

(Excuse me for my English)

I make a clarification... The problem is: when It uses `getX()` or `getY()` and you scale the view asocied to `MotionEvent` (e.g. by Selecting a fragment of text in Edittext), events don't work well. [This image shows an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cozhv.png)

Comment: Why must you change the way an existing class works? Why not just create your own code that does what you want?

Comment: Beacause when I scale a view, that events don't work well by using `getX()` and `getY()`. For example, if you scale an Edittext and you select  a fragment of text for copy it, pointers don't follow the finger, but it moves slow and stays behind.